# Como crear variables dinámicamente con un array o similar

Tags: javascript, array, google-maps, leaflet

estoy creando una aplicación donde utilizo una api de mapas para crear mapas personalizados, estos mapas incluyen unos **Iconos** esos icono se crean de la siguiente manera con **JavaScript**:

```
       var iglesia = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/marker-iglesia.png',
            iconSize: [45, 45], 
        });

        var libreia = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/marker-libreria.png',
            iconSize: [45, 45], 
        });

        var cafe = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/marker-cafe.png',
            iconSize: [45, 45], 
        });

        var marinka = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/marker-marinka.png',
            iconSize: [45, 45], 
        });
```

pero esa manera es muy estática, lo que yo quisera hacer es traer datos de la base de datos como el **iconUrl** y el **iconSize** y crear dinámicamente esas variables con los datos, he intentado hacerlo con un array pero no he logrado ningún resultado.

Espero su ayuda gracias.

Comment: hola @Talked, me parece que lo estas mirando desde el punto de vista equivocado. Lo correcto seria cargar esos datos en un array y modificar tu scrpt de maps para leer esos datos desde el array. Mas alla de eso se me ocurre una opción. Lo que puedes hacer es escribir con js un archivo de texto, luego lo guardas como .js y agregas el include donde lo vayas a usar.  Saludos!

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que esos iconos se agregan de la siguiente manera  marker.setIcon(icono) donde "icono" es una variable, es por eso que necesito hacer crear esas variables.

Comment: Lo único que podrías cambiar a definir una estructura json en un archivo importarlo y luego hacer el for y dentro del for el L.icon

Comment: Ya lo se @Talked. Ya trabaje con maps. Hagamos una cosa.. Edita la pregunta y pone el código donde asignas los valores del icono. De ese modo no estaremos hablando en el aire. Cualquiera va a poder editar tu código y darte una solución.